# Meaning of “Versandhaus”

Tags: meaning

I tried Google Translate but I think that the translation it gave me — *mail order house* — is wrong.

What does the word *Versandhaus* mean?

Does it mean *to sell home appliance by internet*?

Comment: You may want to look in a real dictionary in the future.

Comment: My favourite online dictionary is linguee: http://www.linguee.de/deutsch-englisch/search?source=auto&query=Versandhaus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Today, "Versandhaus" is a synonym for an e-commerce vendor, a company that sells (retail) goods over the internet. The word "Versandhaus" predates the internet and used to refer to mail-order businesses.

The word "Haus" in "Versandhaus" means company, not home. "Versand" means shipping.

On a side note, a company selling and shipping home appliances could be called a "Heimgeräteversandhaus" (not in common usage). Here, "Heim" translates as home.

Comment: "used to refer to mail-order businesses" - it still does, and even though less people may order by mail, catalogues of such businesses still typically include printed forms that can be sent as product ordering postcards. And anyway, for as long as I can think, such businesses have accepted orders by phone, too, so the term "mail-order business" should not be interpreted too literally.

Answer (score 2):

It's a company that *ships* the items you order (as opposed to a local store). They ship either by mail or with the help of a shipping agency, like UPS, DHL, FedEx, ….

A typical "Versandhaus" is *amazon* or *alibaba*. In Germany *Otto* is one of their competitors.

Comment: Amazon isn't a *Versandhaus* but a logistics company in their own view. Why? Because other companies in the *Versandhaus* business made a wage agreement Amazon doesn't want to accept.